# Use a child type in the parent type declaration

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class Shape {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    Line GetTangent();
}
class Line:Shape { ... }
```

It did not work because the type `Line` had not been declared yet.
What can I do?

Comment: this is slightly off question, but lines don't strike me as a natural child of shapes. I would worry that's a bad abstraction.

Comment: I agree. A line is more of a component of shapes, not a specialisation. Shapes are typically 2D elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward your class.

```
class Line;

class Shape 
{
public:
    Line GetTangent();
};

class Line : Shape
{

}

Line Shape::GetTangent()
{
    // Do sth
}
```

C++ requires the type to be complete, when being used. In `Shape` you only notify compiler that you will use `Line` class, but you don't actually use it. Also, if you - for example - return `Line *` or `Line &` (which, in a way, is a pointer too), it should also work, because compiler will work with pointers only (no need to know, what the pointer's target is).

On the other hand, if you try to instantiate Line *inside the Shape class*, it won't work, because C++ doesn't know, how does *Line* look, what kind of constructors does it have and so on. So for that to work, you should provide implementation of the GetTangent method *after* the whole definition of the Line class, as shown in the example.

This is what you will get when trying to use Line inside of Shape: http://ideone.com/YQOjQH
On the other hand, if you extract the definition of GetTangent outside, it will work: http://ideone.com/ZrOgdR

Comment: I wouldn't work as long as GetTanget returns a Line by value, and not by ref.

Comment: Is it because the compiler doesn't know how much stack to allocate for the return value?

Comment: @CătălinPitiș It is OK to return an incolplete type by value in a function *declaration*. But any code calling it will need the complete class definition.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to forward declare `Line` and then return it from methods like `GetTangent` as either a reference or a pointer. You can't return it my value as the compiler won't know how to do it as it hasn't seen the definition of `Line`.

Returning by pointer or reference is probably going to be a pain, so you might want to rethink your class hierarchy. For example, it'll praboly be easier to not have `Line` derive from `Shape`.